# Eclipse Persistence no entities listed

Tags: eclipse, jpa

How do I get my entities in Eclipse to be listed under the JPA facet like in the following screenshot?

[image]

I thought I had basically two identical project setups but I cannot not figure out why one lists the entities and the other one does not.  In the one that does not, I do have classes annotated as such:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class CarDoor {
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1"
>
    <persistence-unit name="gchPU">
        <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/gchjdbc</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property
                name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="drop-and-create" />
            <property
                name="hibernate.show_sql"
                value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: Do you have a `persistence.xml`? What's in it?

Comment: yes, I have a persistence.xml. I just added it to my question.